# MySQL Table Data Import Wizard uploads 0 records when I change column data type to datetime

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

I am using MacOS Monterey. I am using MySQL Workbench to do this.

I have a small table in which one of the columns is `order_date` and I want to use the Table Data Import Wizard to upload this table into a database in MySQL. The entire table is just 10 records in total.

When I upload the table without changing the `order_date` to datetime, all 10 records upload successfully. However, when I try to upload the table and change the data type for the `order_date` column to datetime, it uploads 0 records. I am not sure why this is happening.

In the csv file itself, the `order_date` column is set to 'Date' when I open it using Excel.

The table I am using:

[image: CSV file preview]

The csv file:

```
prod_name,prod_id,order_date,amount
Motorola,1,1/1/2020,1000
Canon Camera,2,2/1/2020,60000
Mousepad,3,3/1/2020,2000
Razer,4,4/1/2020,3000
ABC,5,5/1/2020,1200
DEF,6,6/1/2020,2500
XYZ,7,7/1/2020,90000
ABBBB,8,8/1/2020,123100
ASADASD,9,9/1/2020,1500
Pencil,10,10/1/2020,10
```

Comment: It probably has to do with the import being unable to detect the datetime format, due to these date values it can be both `d/M/y` and `M/d/y`. Maybe there a parameter to set the date format explicitly by hand? Either that or just change the csv file so that the values are like `2020-01-01`.

Comment: @BdR I tried changing to the datetime format suggested (`2020-01-01`) but it still seems to fail. I tried a couple of other formats but still no luck :( Thank you for your suggestion.